# Can´t use form with qtip2. (Events won´t activate.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, qtip2

I'm trying to use qtip and create an embedded form that are being displayed in the qtip. When I'm trying to create a submit event to my form nothing happens. I'm using jquery 1.7 and the latest qtip version.

I have tried to use examples from http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/ but their demos won´t work for me. Please take a look at my code and tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
$("#addNews").qtip({
    position: {
       corner: {
          target: 'bottomMiddle',
          tooltip: 'topMiddle'
       },
       adjust: { x: 0, y: 0 }
    },
    show: {
        when: { event: 'click' },
        solo: true
    },
    hide: {
        fixed: true,
        when: { event: 'unfocus' }
    },
    content: { 
        text: '<form id="frmAddNews"><div class="inputWrap left"><div class="label">Rubrik</div><input type="text" id="" name="" class="inputText" value="" /></div><div class="inputWrap left"><div class="labelTextarea">Meddelande</div><textarea id="" name="" class="inputTextarea" value=""></textarea></div><div class="submit_container"><input type="submit" value="Lägg till nyhet" /></div><div style="clear:both"></div></form>',
    },
    style: {
        border: {
            width: 5,
            radius: 2,
            color: '#e1e1e1'
        },
        width: 350,
        background: '#FFF',
        padding: 15,
        tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
        name: 'cream' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
    },
    events: {
       render: function(event, api) {
             $('form', this).bind('submit', function(event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 console.log("hej");
             });
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But are you sure your `<form>` is embedded in `"#addNews"`? Your jQuery selector `$('form', this)` could be the problem...

Comment: I'm trying to use a form that is displayed inside a qtip. I've tried to use console.log just inside the render-function but it won't even go in there. The text inside content consists of my form.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick play and I got it to work if I set the tooltip to display modally.

i.e. have your `show` option object as:

```
show: {
     event: 'click', // Show it on click...
     modal: {
        on: true,

        // Don't let users exit the modal in any way
        blur: false, escape: false
     }
},
```

[The jsFiddle I was using](http://jsfiddle.net/s7ngG/) to play around with.

Comment: Then that would explain it - he says he is using the latest qtip version but is using old syntax.

Comment: I copied your your code but it still don´t work. Are there any other old syntax that I might have to remove?

Comment: I do not see that on my (quick) first read. You are right, I think we found the mistake. *EDIT* : Yes, same with `hide` object.
*2nd EDIT* : Your `position` object is written in old syntax too. See [this](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/position/) and adapt it.

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem was that I were using some old syntax probably.

Comment: So you resolved your problem? If so, don't forget to mark this as the answer then.